# Passing null to an optional parameter with default value null

Tags: c#, null, optional-parameters

I have a method that have one optional with default value `null`. I have observed that, those who are consuming that method are passing `null` as value for the optional parameter

Main Method

```
public void MainMethod(int id, MyClass model = null)
{
  // Logic goes here
}
```

There are 2 types of invocations i can see,

```
public void First()
{
  MainMethod(1, null);
}

public void Second()
{
  MainMethod(1);
}
```

Will both of them will be having same performance? Or is one better than another one?

Comment: Both are the same. The first has the benefit of working consistently even if the default is changed.

Comment: @mjwills: note that if `MyClass` is a class, the default won't change unless C# changes -- no default other than `null` can apply since no other compile-time constant for `MyClass` is possible. (The general point stands, of course.)

Comment: Agreed @JeroenMostert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They will both result in the exact same IL. In `Second`, the compiler just provides the argument for you automatically.

Defaults are always applied by the compiler at the call site (the piece of code calling the method). That has various downsides - particularly in terms of handling changes to the default value - but it does make it easy to reason about performance etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet do you think order of parameters could be of importance as well?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I don't know what you mean by that. You'd to give more details - which might be better asked in a new question.

Answer (score -3):

I think calling the MainMethod (1) with  default value is a little faster, when we pass a parameter that is null it is necessary to check if it is one to assign the null value again.`

I have executed the calls in a loop to calculate the execution time and this is the result:

```
        TimeSpan stop;
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
             MainMethod(1, null);
        }
        
        stop = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        TimeSpan stop2;
        TimeSpan start2 = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            MainMethod(1);
        }

        stop2 = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        Console.WriteLine(stop.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(stop2.Subtract(start2).TotalMilliseconds);



        public static void MainMethod(int id, MyClass model = null)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is Not null");
            }
        }
```

result

> call MainMethod(1):   7996,862 ms
>
> call MainMethod(1, null):   848,0054 ms

Comment: If you want to microbenchmark, use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). It avoids exactly the kinds of pitfalls that your benchmark is running afoul of.

Comment: Note that the *vast* majority of the time here is spent writing to the console. Without the `Console.WriteLine`, 10,000 calls to this method would go by in the blink of an eye.